# Multiple WebViews in a single Activity

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using WebViews to display multiple animated gifs.
Here is my code :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);

        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        String myWord = myintent.getStringExtra("word");

        LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for(int i = 0; i < myKelime.length(); i++)
        {

            WebView wView = new WebView(this);
            //setting image resource
            switch (myWord.charAt(i)){
                case 'a':         wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.gif");
                    setContentView(wView);
                    break;
                case 'b' :         wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/b.gif");
                    setContentView(wView);
                    break;
                case 'c' :         wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/c.gif");
                                  setContentView(wView); 
                                                              break;

//goes until z

}
            wView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linearLayout.addView(wView);
            //make visible to program
            setContentView(linearLayout);


        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get this error :

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mypc.myapp/com.example.mypc.myapp.MyActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

This was working when I was using ImageView instead of WebView.. How can I get rid of this, and display multiple webviews correctly? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I added this code, it solved :

```
    if(wView.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)wView.getParent()).removeView(wView);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `setContentView()` twice in your code. This might be the reason. It is not recommended to use `setContentView(`) multiple times in same Activity.Try using different Fragments if you need to implement this.